# I have trying to make the border of my box to point toward the side of the screen. Any suggestion?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hoover-i8lqd

In the demo, you can see that the borders of the `control_group` are pointing toward the center of the div, as in the following image:

[image]

In the `test_group`, I am trying to reverse the borders, as in the following image:

[image]

After reading some discussion, I have tried to use the before element in various way but I am still searching for the proper way to get the border pointing toward the side of the screen -in fact, in the reverse from the original's box-.

How can I make the border to point toward the screen?

here the ReactJS snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="control_group"> 
        <h2>a superb reverse border</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="test_group"> 
        <h2>a superb reverse border</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here the CSS' snippet:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* control group */
.control_group {
  background: cyan;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;

  /* flexbox just for cosmetic */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.control_group {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  border-left: solid 1.5vw black;
  border-right: solid 1.5vw black;
  border-radius: 1.5%;
  border-left: solid;
  border-right: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 15px;
}

/* test group */
.test_group {
  position: relative;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;

  /* flexbox just for cosmetic */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.test_group:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-left: solid 1.5vw black;
  border-right: solid 1.5vw black;
  border-radius: 1.5%;
}
```

Comment: why dont you apply the borders on :before.:after pseudo-elements in reverse order, meaning for example the before element is on the left with only border on the ringht and vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pseudo-elements `:after` and `:before`.
`:before` would be on the left and `:after` on the right. You need to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element.

```
/* test group */
.test_group {
  position: relative;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* flexbox just for cosmetic */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.test_group:before,
.test_group:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-left: solid 12px black;
  border-right: solid 12px black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.test_group:before {
  left: calc(-100% - 12px);
}

.test_group:after {
  right: calc(-100% - 12px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would conisder a combination of radial-gradient/linear-gradient to achieve this:

```css
.box {
  --b:20px;  /* control the border */
  --c:black; /* the color */
  
  width:400px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:5px;
  /*control the distance from top and bottom*/
  border-top:20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
  /**/
  padding:10px calc(var(--b) + 5px); /* make sure the padding is at least equal to the borders */
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) top right   /var(--b) var(--b),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) top left    /var(--b) var(--b),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) bottom right/var(--b) var(--b),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) bottom left /var(--b) var(--b),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) left /var(--b) calc(100% - 2*var(--b)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) right/var(--b) calc(100% - 2*var(--b)),
    yellow;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit quam eu nisi convallis aliquam. Donec non fringilla massa. Praesent malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.
</div>

<div class="box" style="--b:40px;--c:blue">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit quam eu nisi convallis aliquam. Donec non fringilla massa. Praesent malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum. malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.
</div>

<div class="box" style="--b:10px;--c:red">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit quam eu nisi convallis aliquam. Donec non fringilla massa. Praesent malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum. malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.
</div>
```

Use a different color for each gradient to understand the puzzle:

```css
.box {
  --b:20px;  /* control the border */
  
  width:400px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:5px;
  /*control the distance from top and bottom*/
  border-top:20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
  /**/
  padding:10px calc(var(--b) + 5px); /* make sure the padding is at least equal to the borders */
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,red 98%,transparent 100%) top right   /var(--b) var(--b),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,blue 98%,transparent 100%) top left    /var(--b) var(--b),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,green 98%,transparent 100%) bottom right/var(--b) var(--b),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,purple 98%,transparent 100%) bottom left /var(--b) var(--b),
    linear-gradient(gray,gray) left /var(--b) calc(100% - 2*var(--b)),
    linear-gradient(black,black) right/var(--b) calc(100% - 2*var(--b)),
    yellow;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit quam eu nisi convallis aliquam. Donec non fringilla massa. Praesent malesuada leo lorem, non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.non fermentum nulla auctor bibendum. Cras eget vestibulum ipsum. Nullam iaculis auctor odio id condimentum.
</div>
```